# Unable to upload document with special character in AWS CloudSearch through Java SDK

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to upload a document which has special character in it. The JSON string is

```js
[{
  "type": "add",
  "id": 1234,
  "fields": {
    "copyrightline": "© 2005 Some company.  All Rights Reserved."
  }
}]
```

When i remove '©' from the json, i am able to upload the document. When i have the character '©' the below is the error

> AmazonCloudSearchDomainException: The request signature we calculated
>   does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret
>   Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for
>   details. (Service: AmazonCloudSearchDomain; Status Code: 403; Error
>   Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID:
>   d11a2497-aeac-11e9-b6fb-db6602f3004a)

Tried changing the encoding (`UTF-8`, `UTF-16` and `UTF-32`) but with no success.

Here is the code which push the above string to `CloudSearch`

```
UploadDocumentsRequest uploadDocumentsRequest = new UploadDocumentsRequest();
InputStream inputStream = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toInputStream(testDataString, "UTF-8");
uploadDocumentsRequest.setDocuments(inputStream);
uploadDocumentsRequest.setContentType(ContentType.Applicationjson);
uploadDocumentsRequest.setContentLength((long) testData.length());
UploadDocumentsResult uploadDocumentsResult = client.uploadDocuments(uploadDocumentsRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the issue is with setContentLength(). If the length is invalid the error is thrown.  So the following code change made sure it works.

```
uploadDocumentsRequest.setContentLength((long) cloudSearchAddRequest.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
```